# Can 是 be changed into 的?

Tags: meaning

I have been playing a farming game these days and I joined a Chinese neighborhood in the game. There’s a chatting room feature that allows members of the neighborhood to chat with one another.

I don’t know if my understanding is correct but I feel like some people change 是 into 的 when they talk.
Examples:

> A: 大家都做就能进三甲, B: 不一定, 冠军的很难得

Shouldn’t it be something like “冠军是难的?”

> There’s a female member that tried to be friendly and sent the kissing emoji () to other member in my neighborhood but turned out it was a guy she did this to and the guy replied with: ”亲嘛, 我的男生”

Shouldn’t it be “我是男生”?

Of course, I might misunderstand what they said due to my low level Chinese. But if my understanding is correct, do 的…得 equal 是…的 and 的 equal 是 in this case?

Comment: It is hard to tell without more context and a better understanding of the game (and the events in the game). But in general, 是 cannot be changed into 的.

Comment: I heard sentences like your example 我的男生 from native speakers in colloquial settings,   so it doesn't sound totally foreign to me, however I can't pinpoint a pattern. In general, I agree with fefe, 是 and 的 are never interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

These 2 sentences are not grammatically correct. Instead, they should be:
不一定，冠军（是）很难得（的）。 and  我是男生。

They look more like typing errors to me, since 's' and 'd' are quite close on the keyboard. You should never find people replace 是 with 的 in formal cases.

Answer (score 0):

难得 and 难的 have totally different meaning...

难的, or 困难的 means "hard":

想要当冠军很难的：Want to be a champion is hard.

难得 means "hard to get/see" or "rare to happen":

难得看到他吃水果：it's rare to see him eat fruits.